# Deploy a program that includes Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity assembly

Tags: c#, deployment, connectivity, smart-device

I am using Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity assembly as a part of a larger application. Now I have to deploy that application and I can't find any info in regarding to deploying such applications. Even on the msdn resource page there is a question regarding this issue, with no replys.

So how can I deploy such an application. Is there a list of assemblys I have to deploy or something?

I have included the Misrosoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.dll however the application is still missing at least one file: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Connectivity.Interop.dll" I can't find that file anywhere. How can I deploy this application on a machine without visual studio installed.

**How can I deploy the application on a computer without visual studio?** Is there a SmartDevice Connectivity API redistributable or something?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called [IsoStoreSpy.application](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/). You can use it to deploy applications. 
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but these libraries are in the NuGet package managerment framework  which should allow you to include references. Set the project's build to copy all package-managed DLLs into the output directory of your executable.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Smartdevice.Connectivity/